# SQL Server Counting Two Columns

Tags: sql, count

Is it possible to count two columns?

I have a table that stores application names and which users have launched over time.

When querying a date range you end up with a result like the below example.

```
| App   | User   |
| App A | User A |
| App A | User A |
| App A | User B |
| App A | User C |
| App A | User D |
| App A | User D |
| App A | User D |
| App B | User A |
| App B | User E |
| App B | User F |
| App C | User A |
| App C | User C |
| App C | User C |
| App C | User C |
| App C | User F |
```

What I'm trying to get is one column that shows the number of app launches per app and another showing the number of users launching that app.

I can't figure out how to do it.

Any one any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  App
,       count(*) as Launches
,       count(distinct [User]) as Users
from    Table1
group by
        App
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b13c9/2)

The square brackets around `[User]` are for SQL Server.  Without them, you'd get your own username instead of the `User` column.  In MySQL, you'd use backticks.